# Functional equation with two variables but unknown functions only have one variable

Tags: functional-analysis

For motivation, consider $Y = g(X) + U$ where $(X,Y)$ has some given joint distribution $f_{X,Y}$, $g$ is an unknown nonparametric function and the distribution of $U$, $f_U$, is unknown and independent of $X$. Basically I am interested in identification of the nonparametric function g (I have some other equations and the equation above is not exactly what I use). After manipulation and Fourier transformation I land up with the functional equation,
\begin{align}
r(f_{X,Y};x,y) &=\int f_U(t) g(x-t) \frac{r_1(x-t,y)}{r_2(f_U;x-t)}dt
\end{align}
where $g$ is the unknown function, $f_U$ is the unknown density of $U$ and $r$, $r_1$ and $r_2$ are known functions/functionals.

I am wondering what are the conditions for finding solutions to  $g$ (and $f_U$) and how to find them.

edit: made the question more specific with motivation

Answer (score 1):

It is strange what you have written.

As we can clearly see from the left-hand side, $g$ is a function mapping $S\times T$ to some values, but on the right hand side, $h$ appears to map $\Phi \times \Psi \times T$ to some values. This is explained by the fact that on the right hand side, our first two arguments are completely related through the sole independent variable $s$. As a first step, I would disavow the notion that there are two separate functions $\phi$ and $\psi$.

For instance, consider the polynomial $f(x) = x^2+x+1$. This is clearly a function of one variable. But, if we wished to really complicate matters and holistically abuse functional notation, we could define $\phi(x) = x$ and $\psi(x) = x^2$ and then say $f(x) = g(\phi(x),\psi(x)) = \phi(x)+\psi(x)+1$. This has little practicable purpose.

In general, supposing you did have $\phi(s)$ and $\psi(s)$, it is most sensible to use the implicit function theorem to find the domain wherein $\phi$ is solvable in terms of $\psi$ and then treat it as a single function. Then you are left with a basic problem of identifying solution of $g(s,t) = \hat{h}(s,t)$, which can again be treated either as an implicit function theorem problem, or if this is an applied problem for which you have data, as an inverse problem. However, as with any data analysis problem, finding analytic closed forms is all but impossible.

Without knowing more, your question cannot be answered. However, some "nice" properties to start with would be differentiability of $g$ on its domain, differentiability of $h$ on its domain, and solvability of $\phi$ in terms of $\psi$ or vice-versa.

Comment: I edited the question with some motivation for why I am interested in the function and made the equation more specific.